# make compiling in "safe mode" for a C++ program

Tags: c++

Does make have an option that makes the programs compile safely so that things that cause undefined behavior would instead generate a runtime error; an example being an array out of bounds? Of course, this would mean that the program runs more slowly.

If make itself doesn't have an option, would there be another debug tool that is make-compatible?

Comment: You know that make just calls your compiler, and that if at all (and it is impossible to catch all UB) the compiler would need to have the options to compile with such a feature?

Comment: I don't think make has much (if anything) to do with this. It must be the compiler options. What are your compiler and platform? What kind of runtime error do you want? UB is already a runtime error. Do you want an explicit crash or debug break during UB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If C++ had this feature, it would be Java. Or Python. Or C#. Or ... you get the idea.

There is also 'Managed C++', which is a bit of a camel that could perhaps serve your purposes.

On Non-Windows platforms, the valgrind tool is the next best thing.

Various versions of Microsoft C++ have had options that add some extra checking, but nothing on the scale of these other things.

Comment: The first sentence is a bit of a stretch, and it wouldn't have to be a language feature, just a compiler feature. Just trapping, or terminating the process, would be enough for OP. The languages you name, on the other hand, pretty much always allow detecting the error and ignoring it. Note that at least in Python and C#, there are still ways to corrupt memory.

Comment: virtual -1 for the first sentence.  That's just silly.  If the feature is optional, then C++ would still be nothing like those languages.

Comment: The problem is that C++ explicitly allows various unsafe operations. The compiler *cannot* 'trap or terminate'. The compile would need considerable assistance from the runtime -- and then you have valgrind, and performance best described as 'stately'.

Comment: Actually, if a program invokes undefined behavior, the compiler can do anything it wants, including emitting a friendly error message at compile time (if it can catch it then) or at runtime.  And if the checks are optional, and you only have them on during debugging, performance isn't your primary concern.

Comment: C++ does not "allow" any UB -- that's why it's *undefined* ;) +1 to @BenjaminLindley's comment. Yes, runtime checks are needed for some UB, but not for all. Valgrind does considerably more than is necessary for UB detection -- it is a full CPU emulator, which is why it can also do things like measuring cache behaviour, creating call graphs and profiling data, detect orphaned memory (not deallocating alone isn't UB). Valgrind also does *not* detect various undefined behaviours, such as certain kinds of integer overflow (others are well-defined).

Comment: I guess a good debug mode would generate runtime errors like Java does with (usually) pinpoint precision. The problems with memory management errors is that they do not generate immediate feedback about where and when things went undefined.

Comment: Yes, valgrind seems to do the trick (most of the time): It allows you to simply specify a compile flag and then prints out Java-esque runtime errors. See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.prepare

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge (15+years of experience) MSVC does not have anything like that. I also never heard about this in other compilers.

Comment: And MSVC has hardly more to do with make than make has to do with C++ undefined behaviour...

Comment: Make can only pass a key to the compiler. MSVC can do something in this area. At the same time you cannot blame a 5 ton truck that it cannot carry 10 tons. MSVC has many other nice features. Well, this one is missing.